# Switch position between left and right

Tags: html, image, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I have multiple articles with an image for each article, and i'm using Flexbox to style my page, what i'm trying to do is to switch between the article and image every other row, so the first row should be like (article - image) then (image-article) then again (article-image) etc .. here is the first article code with the styling, and let me know if i'm doing anything wrong or if you have a better suggestion.

```css
div {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  display: block;
}

.article {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}

.article-content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 48.6666666%;
  text-align: left;
}

.img-control {
  margin-left: 3.5%;
  width: 48%;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.img-control .image {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="article">
  <div class="article-content">
    <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="img-control">
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url(//via.placeholder.com/490x338);"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `nth-child` and Flexbox's `order` to accomplish that, where you with i.e. `even` can target every second (2, 4, ..) `article`, and then put the `.img-control` before the text, using `order: -1`.

```css
div {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  display: block;
}

.article {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}

.article-content {
  width: 48.6666666%;
  text-align: left;
}

.article:nth-child(even) .img-control {
  order: -1;
  margin-right: 3.5%;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.img-control {
  margin-left: 3.5%;
  width: 48%;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.img-control .image {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="article">
  <div class="article-content">
    <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="img-control">
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url(//via.placeholder.com/490x338);"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="article">
  <div class="article-content">
    <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="img-control">
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url(//via.placeholder.com/490x338);"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="article">
  <div class="article-content">
    <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="img-control">
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url(//via.placeholder.com/490x338);"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="article">
  <div class="article-content">
    <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="img-control">
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url(//via.placeholder.com/490x338);"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know why its not working on my page!  and its even selecting the **.img-control div** for some reason. is there any other way i can do this ?

Comment: @Abdal Show me a link to the page

Comment: @Abdal In that code you also have an extra element, `<div class="clear under-line"></div>`, which make the above `nth-child(even)` won't work, use `nth-child(3n+3)` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/39j6995s/5/

Comment: @Abdal When I woke up today I realized their is a mistake in the above update, it should be `.article:nth-child(4n+3)` if there will be more than 3 items ... http://jsfiddle.net/39j6995s/6/ ... let me know that this works for you

Comment: yeah i was wondering why it didn't work the first one, now it worked fine, but can you explain why you did 4n+3. and thank you so much.

Comment: @Abdal Since every 1,3,5,etc is your `article` and every 2,4,6,etc is your `underline`, the 3 mean start from the 3rd element (which is the 2nd article) and the 4n mean target every 4th element (which will be every 2nd article)

Comment: Thank you! that was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can have one dynamic div which contains two static divs, one with article-image and one with image-article. Like this:

```
<div id='dynamic div'>
<div class="article">
    <div class="article-content">
        <div class="img-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="article">
    <div class="img-control">
    </div>
    <div class="article-content">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so what would be the styling for dynamic and div Classes ?

Comment: Styling would be as you had it, although LGSons' answer about is less and 'cleaner' code.